# Hanging indents in React JS

Tags: css, reactjs

Most CSS code seems to work just fine in React JS, however, I am trying to use `text-indent` to make a hanging indent. A hanging indent is where the first line of text is outdented (indented to the left). Normally, in CSS I can use `text-indent: -10px` and it works fine. In React JS I would normally do something like `textIndent: "-10px"`. However, `textIndent` seems to have no effect in React JS.

What is the reason that React JS does not like this CSS property? What can I do instead?

Comment: It does have effect, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-edxd1k .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, most likely, you are passing the text-indent directly to the paragraph element. The warning will go away if you pass text-indent to a wrapping parent div instead. Good luck!

Comment: To [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24051652): if the answer is an attempt to answer the question, don't recommend deletion! See, for example, "[You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007)" and "[When an answer answers the wrong question, is it Not An Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185162/284827)". This is an answer. You may not agree with it, but it is an attempt to answer the question.